# ESO Recommended Server for India

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

What is the recommended server for Elder Scrolls Online for someone in India?

While I was installing the game, the installer recommended North America.

Also as per their current FAQ, both North America and Europe servers are hosted in North America, albeit separately.

But they said they would be moving the EU server to EU soon.

That being said what would be the best server to connect to in order to minimize latency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. Right now, both servers are located in the US, so you won't notice any significant ping/lag/latency difference. However - as you said - the EU server will be moved to Europe (I think Frankfurt, but don't quote me on that).

That being said, it's hard to say how/if latency will change for you. If you don't have any issues so far, I wouldn't worry too much about lag alone. It can't get worse, it may only improve.

Geographically, I'd assume the European server would be the better choice for you, since it's quite a bit closer to you. This also means that your prime time won't be that far off compared to other players playing there.

Overall, you should try to see where your friends are playing, assuming you already know people you'd like to stick with for this game.

What you definitely should keep in mind are server downtimes, which will follow different schedule for NA/EU as stated [here](https://help.elderscrollsonline.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7658/kw/server%20maintenance) (you might have to try to open that link twice for it to show the proper article for whatever reason):

> **Tuesday (Patches)**
>
> 00:01 am EDT (06:01 CEST) - EU
>
> 08:00 am EDT (14:00 CEST) - NA
>
> **Friday (Reboot/Hotfixes)**
>
> 00:01 am EDT (06:01 CEST) - EU
>
> 08:00 am EDT (14:00 CEST) - NA
>
> **North American Megaserver**
>
> Tuesdays at 8:00 am EDT (14:00 CEST)
>
> Fridays at 8:00 am EDT (14:00 CEST)
>
> **European Megaserver**
>
> Tuesdays at 00:01 am EDT (6:00 am CEST)
>
> Fridays at 00:01 am EDT (6:00 am CEST)

After all, you most likely don't want downtimes to happen during your playing time all the time.

Comment: You can't transfer server so far, although that's a service they might offer later on. If you want to switch to EU, you'll have to start from scratch (for now). Also keep in mind that they're applying a small hotfix to EU right now, so that server should (or has been) down as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm from the same region as you(Sri Lanka) and as the other posters have pointed out both the EU and US mega servers are currently located in the US(Dallas, Texas). However, once the EU server is migrated to Germany(Frankfurt) I'm pretty sure that it would be the clear winner in terms of latency. I have been playing wow on the EU servers since couple of years and my average latency is around 140 ms while I get 350+ ms to the US data centers. Hope this helps.